# Game distorted my panel

Tags: panel

After installing a game, it messed up my panel.

On the far left used to be an icon for shutdown etc, then the date, and my battery icon.

Can it be repaired?

[image]

Comment: Looks like its still there just needs resized. I think you hold down ALT and Right Click....

Comment: Alt Right click just brings up add to panel,properties,etc.

Comment: I don't use Gnome Panel so we need someone else to help you re-add it. It is part of that ALT-R-Click though.